# Scroll multiple CollectionView cell inside TableView Cell

Tags: swift, collections, tableview, collectionview

I'm in trouble. I have a TableView with inside a CollectionView with horizontal scroll.

Is there a possibility to swipe at the same time all the CollectionViewCells in all the rows?

At the moment, the behaviour is that each row is independently scrolling horizontally.

Thanks!

Comment: Collection view is in table view cell or opposite?

Comment: Collection view is inside the rows of table view

Comment: Maybe you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012613/horizontally-scroll-all-rows-of-uicollectionview-together and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008620/synchronize-scrolling-with-two-collection-views-in-swift/39016708#39016708

Comment: I'll check it out, but I'm not completely convinced about it.